# Pressing enter inside number cells excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I'm trying to do a `SUMIF` and it seems I have to go cell by cell, previously, and press <kbd>enter</kbd>. As you can see in the image I pressed enter and numbers have gone to the right. Data is in tab 1 and formula is build in tap 2 this could be a reason that explains all?

[image: screenshot]

Why does this happen?

And what can I do to solve this problem instead of pressing one by one cell?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the text formatting before had it as text, and when you put the formula it kept that way. Now, when you go line by line it identifies as a "change", and correctly formats as number.

You can either select the entire column and select "Align to Right" or you use the replace tool (Its CTRL+U in PTBR, but CTRL+F in US version) and replace something by itself. For example, if there are still formulas, you may try to replace SUMIF with SUMIF, or ( with (. This will force an update on the cells, which has the same effect as pressing Enter.

Comment: I would just note that align-right for text isn't a great solution because it leaves it as text.  That could cause unexpected errors.  Many math operations will handle it, but text doesn't always behave like numbers.